# Convert the answer entered by the user to lowercase and write to screen

Tags: javascript

Nothing is being written to screen.

Console error shows this:

> ReferenceError: `ans` is not defined**

Here is code:

The expected result should be the user input from prompt be manipulated to lower case and written to page.

Any help would be considered. thx

```js
function lowerCase(ans) {
  var lowCase = ans.toLowerCase();
  return lowerCase;
}

var questions = ['How may strings does a violin have?', 'How many sides does an octagon have?',
  'How many NBA championships did Michael Jordan win with the Chicago Bulls?'
];

var answers = ['FOUR', 'EIGHT', 'SIX'];

var score = 0;

function quiz(counter) {
  var guesses = 3;

  while (guesses > 0) {
    var ans = prompt(questions[counter]);
    if (ans == answers[counter]) {
      alert("Correct!");
      return guesses;
    } else {
      guesses--;
      alert("Incorrect, You have " + guesses + " guesses remaining");
    }
  }
  return 0;
}

document.write(lowerCase(ans));
```

Comment: brr `prompt` `alert` `document.write`, this code is good for Halloween.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the function instead of   `return lowerCase;` do `return lowCase;`. You are returning the function again instead you have to return the variable which contains the lowercase text. Define `ans` in global scope not inside the while loop. You have to call the quiz function too. `document.write` should be inside the quiz function not outside it

```js
function lowerCase(ans) {
  var lowCase = ans.toLowerCase();
  return lowCase;
}

var ans='';

var questions = ['How may strings does a violin have?', 'How many sides does an octagon have?',
  'How many NBA championships did Michael Jordan win with the Chicago Bulls?'
];
var answers = ['FOUR', 'EIGHT', 'SIX'];

var score = 0;

function quiz(counter) {
  var guesses = 3;



  while (guesses > 0) {
     ans = prompt(questions[counter]);
    if (ans == answers[counter]) {
      alert("Correct!");
      return guesses;
    } else {
      guesses--;
      alert("Incorrect, You have " + guesses + " guesses remaining");
    }
  }
  document.write(lowerCase(ans));
}

quiz(2)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to return `lowCase` from your function - also, move your `document.write` call inside your `quiz` function - and finally, call your `quiz` function:

```js
function lowerCase(ans) {
  var lowCase = ans.toLowerCase();
  return lowCase;
}



var questions = ['How may strings does a violin have?', 'How many sides does an octagon have?',
  'How many NBA championships did Michael Jordan win with the Chicago Bulls?'
];
var answers = ['FOUR', 'EIGHT', 'SIX'];

var score = 0;

function quiz(counter) {
  var guesses = 3;
  while (guesses > 0) {
    var ans = prompt(questions[counter]);
    if (ans == answers[counter]) {
      alert("Correct!");
      document.write(lowerCase(ans) + "<br>");
      return guesses;
    } else {
      guesses--;
      alert("Incorrect, You have " + guesses + " guesses remaining");
    }
  }
  return 0;
}

document.write("You had " + quiz(2) + " guesses remaining after the game ended");
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a little change is required as you listed the error, ReferenceError: ans is not defined. This occurs because of, you're calling the function lowerCase with the argument **ans** but **ans** is having only scope inside the while loop in your code, so better to define it as global variable and make it blank there, afterwords you can override the value in your conditions/loops. 
I hope this clears your issue.

Comment: now i understand. Yes you all helped me tremendously, ty!!

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed the code an commented the changes. You seem to have a scope problem. They way you have written it the ans variable is not visible at the document write. There were some other errors that I have fixed.

```js
function lowerCase(ans) {
  if(!ans){ //Fail safe when empty string sent
      return '';
  }
  var lowCase = ans.toLowerCase();
  return lowCase; // changed returned value to lowCase earlier you were returning 'lowerCase'
}



var questions = ['How may strings does a violin have?', 'How many sides does an octagon have?',
  'How many NBA championships did Michael Jordan win with the Chicago Bulls?'
];
var answers = ['FOUR', 'EIGHT', 'SIX'];

var score = 0;
function quiz(counter) {
  var guesses = 1;
  while (guesses > 0) {
    var ans = prompt(questions[counter]);
    ans = lowerCase(ans); // Lower case conversion done separately for clarity
    document.write('Guess: '+ans+'</br>'); // Moved the document write to a place where answer is  visible
    if (ans === lowerCase(answers[counter])) { // the answer array values were also converted to lower case if not this logic is broken
      alert("Correct!");
      return guesses;
    } else {
      guesses--;
      alert("Incorrect, You have " + guesses + " guesses remaining");
    }
  }
  return 0;
}

quiz(0); // called quiz with zero as an example
```